# Show/"sketch" which area f is strictly positive.

Tags: real-analysis, 3d, differential, monotone-functions, interval-arithmetic

I have the following question:

> Let $c>0$ and consider the following function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by:

> $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
>  c y e^{-x} & \text{0 < x < $\infty$ and 0 < y < $e^{-x}$} \\  
>  0 & \text{else} \\   
>  \end{cases} $$

> 1. "Sketch"/show the area where $f$ is strictly positive.

By the intervals i notice that $y \in (0,1)$ because it's dependent of $x$.

I've plotted the graph, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnOpf.png), and there is a curved area where $f(x,y)>0$, but i have no idea how i formally show or specify the area as an interval or "sketch" it.

I'm pretty stuck on this one, so i hope there is someone who can get me a little push.

Comment: Maybe you're supposed to plot the area on the plane where $f(x, y) > 0$? It's hard to know without knowing more about the question.

Comment: I would expect you to sketch the domain of the function that is strictly positive. Use the bounds of $x$ and $y$ given to produce the boundaries. Note that one boundary is an axis, and the other is the curve of a familiar function.

Comment: Hi, Theo. 
That's all the information we've been given - but, perhaps you're right. The only thing that "bothers" me is that all of the previous questions have been done without CAS-instruments, so i would believe we should continue like that.

Comment: @Mugge I think there'll be more to the question; surely it doesn't just end with point 1? It should be leading somewhere, and if we know where that is, we'll have a better chance of figuring out what is intended. Also, my suggestion doesn't need a CAS: you're just shading a region in the plane.

Comment: @Mugge you should not need CAS here. The boundaries are well defined and you can read them off from the equation given once you sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

First, we know that $0$ is not strictly positive. So, if we don't have $0 < x < \infty$ and $0 < y < e^{-x},$ then $f(x, y)$ is equal to $0$, hence is not strictly positive.

Now, suppose we do have $0 < x < \infty$ and $0 < y < e^{-x}.$ Note that $e^{-x}$ is always strictly positive, $y$ is always strictly positive in this range ($0 < y < e^{-x}$), and that $c$ is strictly positive by assumption. So, $cye^{-x}$ is always strictly positive when $x$ and $y$ are in this range.

So, when we have $0 < x < \infty$ and $0 < y < e^{-x},$ $f(x, y)$ is equal to $cye^{-x},$ and is thus strictly positive.

Therefore, the area where $f$ is strictly positive is just the area in the plane described by $0 < x < \infty$ and $0 < y < e^{-x}.$ So you just need to sketch this.